# nginx timeout when started via systemd unit

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, nginx

My nginx starts well with a `/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` command line, but when I try to start it with:

```
# systemctl start nginx
```

then it hangs until timed out.

My systemd unit looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Documentation=man:nginx(8)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the attempt to start nginx:

```
root@efk:~# systemctl start nginx                                                                                                  
Job for nginx.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.                                                                       
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.                                                             
root@efk:~# systemctl status nginx.service                                                                                         
? nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server                                                         
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)                                             
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2021-10-04 00:32:44 CEST; 1min 25s ago                                               
     Docs: man:nginx(8)                                                                                                            
  Process: 14413 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)                        
  Process: 14403 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)               
 Main PID: 466 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                   
Oct 04 00:31:14 efk systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...                               
Oct 04 00:31:14 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or dir
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.                                             
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 14414 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.                                  
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 14416 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.                                  
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 14417 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.                                  
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.                                                       
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.                          
root@efk:~# journalctl -xe                                                                                                         
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 14414 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 14416 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 14417 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Oct 04 00:32:44 efk systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

But when it is started with:

```
# /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

it works well.

The nginx is:

```
root@efk:~# /usr/sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.21.3 (nginx-quic)
built by gcc 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 (compatible; BoringSSL) (running with BoringSSL)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --build=nginx-quic --with-debug --add-module=../njs/nginx --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_v3_module --with-http_quic_module --with-stream_quic_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --without-select_module --without-poll_module --without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_smtp_module --with-openssl=/home/mtodorov/build/boringssl --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-all -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I /home/mtodorov/build/boringssl/.openssl/include/' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L /home/mtodorov/build/boringssl/.openssl/lib/'
root@efk:~#
```

So the path /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid is compiled-in, so I don't know why the server cannot find it when ran from systemd unit?

Any idea?

Marvin

Answer (score 1):

The problem was stupid. Despite the compiled-in configuration, nginx was using `/var/run/nginx.pid`, not the `/var/run/nginx/nginx.pid` (dissimilar to apache2).

Changing this in the nginx.service unit fixed the problem, and now the `systemctl start nginx` directive works seamless.

Marvin

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem getting nginx to start on ChromeOS. The fix was nearly the same though, in `/etc/init.d/nginx` I changed `PID=/run/nginx.pid` to `PID=/run/nginx/nginx.pid`.

`systemctl start nginx` worked after the change. I'm not entirely sure why apt put it in init.d instead of adding a systemd service, but it works.